# Is there a way to configure Windows 8 start screen to return to a running desktop App rather than launching a new one when I click a tile?

Tags: windows-8, desktop, live-tiles

I find myself going back to the home screen naturally rather than going for the ALT TAB. Then if I click the desktop app shortcut tile it takes me back to the desktop and launches a new window/instance. It seems like this is already the perfect UI to simply take what once was task bar tabs and put them as tiles. Then I could see the current state of my desktop app in the tile, and clicking the tile would restore it to the focus. Not sure why they went half assed, keeping ALT-TAB and leaving the desktop apps out of the tiles interface, rather than just allowing me to full screen a desktop app as a tile.

Thus I am wondering if there is something I can do to the short cut tile to make it go to a running desktop app rather than just being used for launching anew.

Comment: I guess this depends on whether the app allows multiple instances or not. Even with normal desktop shortcuts, depending on the app multiple clicks will either focus the running instance, or will launch a new instance. Also, if multiple instances are allowed, the Start Screen would need to display thumbnail previews of all running apps so you can focus a specific instance of an app, but that goes against the very concept of a **Start** Screen obviously.

Comment: Whether or not a traditional desktop application [ensures a single instance](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ensuring%20a%20single%20instance%20application) has always been up to the developer and typically it isn't done. Breaking that would likely be a major compatibility issue